# Frontend - Add new use jqGrid?

Tags: json, jqgrid, frontend

I use jqGrid add new record, but i can't put data from grid to json string.

When i run, return code:

> error Status: 'Unsupported Media Type'. Error code: 415

And my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
    url: 'http://192.168.1.59:8080/sunrise/api/v1/warehouse/getById/1',
    mtype: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: ['wareHouseID', 'name' , 'fullname' , 'company', 'address'],
    colModel: [
    { name: 'wareHouseID', index: 'wareHouseID', width: 150,editable:false, editoptions:{readonly:true, size:10}, hidden:true},
    { name: 'name', index: 'name', width: 150,editable:true, editoptions:{size:30}},
    { name: 'fullname', index: 'fullname', width: 150,editable:true,editoptions:{size:30}},
    { name: 'company', index: 'company', width: 150,editable:true,editoptions:{size:30}},
    { name: 'address', index: 'address', width: 150,editable:true,editoptions:{size:30}}
  ],
    rowNum: 10,
    rowList:[10,20,30],
    width: 1290,
    sortname: 'wareHouseID',
    sortorder:"desc",
    height:235,
    gridview: true,
    viewrecords: true,
    caption: "List User Details",
    editurl:"http://192.168.1.59:8080/sunrise/api/v1/warehouse/update",
    pager: "#jQGridDemoPager",
    ajaxRowOptions : {
        type :"POST",
        contentType :"application/json",
        dataType :"json"
    },
    serializeRowData: function(postData){     
        return JSON.stringify(postData);
    }
});
$("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid('navGrid','#jQGridDemoPager',
        {edit:true, add:true, del:false, search:true},
        // Edit options
        {
            type:"PUT",
            url:"http://192.168.1.59:8080/sunrise/api/v1/warehouse/update",
            closeAfterEdit:true,
            reloadAfterSubmit:true, 
            onclickSubmit: function(params, postData) {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            afterSubmit: function(response, postData) {
                var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                return [true, "", res.d];   
            }
        },

        //Add option
        {
            type:"POST",
            url:"http://192.168.1.59:8080/sunrise/api/v1/warehouse/new",
            closeAfterAdd:true,reloadAfterSubmit:true, 
            onclickSubmit: function(params, postData) {
                return JSON.stringify(postData);
            },
            afterSubmit: function(response, postData) {
                var res = jQuery.parseJSON(response.responseText);
                return [true, "", res.d];       
            }
        }   
    );});
```

Could you help me to find a problem and how to fix it? Tks very much.

Answer (score 1):

There are many unclear parts in your code. Nevertheless I guess that the main problem which you have is the following: you use `ajaxRowOptions` to set `contentType` and you use `serializeRowData` to serialize the data from request as JSON. The problem is: you use **form editing**, but `ajaxRowOptions` and `serializeRowData` will be used only in case of **inline editing**.

So you should use

```js
ajaxEditOptions: { contentType :"application/json" },
serializeEditData: function (postData) {     
    return JSON.stringify(postData);
}
```

You have to remove `onclickSubmit` which returns `JSON.stringify(postData)` additionally.

I hope it should solve the problem. If it will not help then you should write first of all which version of jqGrid you use and which fork of jqGrid you use ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or some old jqGrid in version <= 4.7). You should write additionally more information about the server which reruns the error "'Unsupported Media Type'. Error code: 415".

Comment: @Zon: You are welcome! Is the problem is solved now?